# How to add Ace code editor to a sphinx page?

Tags: javascript, html, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, code-editor

I have the following RST file:

```
Title
=====


.. raw:: html

    <body>

    <div id="editor">function foo(items) {
        var x = "All this is syntax highlighted";
        return x;
    }</div>
        
    <script src="./src-noconflict/ace.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script>
        var editor = ace.edit("editor");
        editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
        editor.session.setMode("ace/mode/javascript");
    </script>
    </body>
```

I want to add the ace code editor into my sphinx page but no matter what I try the editor does not render and will tell me the following error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: ace is not defined", I believe this is because of error I get before: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found). Sphinx is not able to find ace.js in the directory I chose for ace. Which is src-noconflict. I have the following directory:

```
root_folder
   ...
   src-noconflict/... (ace.js is in this folder)
   content/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/my_page.rst
   ...
```

How can I add the ace-editor to my sphinx page?

Comment: Use [`html_static_path`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-html_static_path) in your `conf.py`, then Sphinx should copy it over from the source to the build directory. I recommend using root-relative paths, instead of file-relative.

Comment: @StevePiercy The thing is that I already did, in my ```conf.py``` file I have the line ```html_static_path = ['_static']```, which is why I am so confused on why this will not work.

Comment: `./src-noconflict/ace.js` is not in `_static`.

Comment: @StevePiercy Yes my very late realization caused this, thanks it works now!